# Melting a table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model in a PGSQL database with three variable, `D1`, `D2`, and `D3`. I would like to use `Chartklick` library to make a multilines chart, with a line for each variable. For that I need to melt the table from `Date, D1, D2, D3` to `Date, Factor`, so that i can group by Product Type and obtain a line for each of the Factor (D1, D2, and D3)
Is there a way to do that please ?

From : 
[image]

to this:
[image]

I have done this so far :

```
`<%= line_chart [                        
{name: "df1", data: MyDataset.group('date', 'factor').where(factor: "factor_df1").sum(:value)},                        
{name: "df2", data: MyDataset.group('date', 'factor').where(factor: "factor_df2").sum(:value)}     ] %>`
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean with *melting a table*. Can you provide an example of input and expected output data?

Comment: @zwippie, I have added the original dataset and the expected dataset as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you want to go from some data:

```rb
[
  {date: "2020-02-21", factor_d1: 1, factor_d2: 1, factor_d3: 3},
  ...
]
```

to:

```rb
[
  {date: "2020-02-21", factor: "factor_d1", value: "1"},
  {date: "2020-02-21", factor: "factor_d2", value: "1"},
  {date: "2020-02-21", factor: "factor_d3", value: "3"},
  ...
]
```

This can be done with [flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```rb
def melt(data)
  data.flat_map do |entry|
    [
      {date: entry[:date], factor: "factor_d1", value: entry[:factor_d1]},
      {date: entry[:date], factor: "factor_d2", value: entry[:factor_d2]},
      {date: entry[:date], factor: "factor_d3", value: entry[:factor_d3]},
    ]
  end
end
```

If you have lots of more `factor_x` elements this could get a little bit bulky and you might want to try another approach.

Comment: Hey, thank you @zwippie. Do you happen to know how to plug this in a charkick multiline chart by any chance pls?

Comment: No, never used that library.